# How Chinese input tools like Microsoft pinyin or google pinyin adapt to different encoding website?

Tags: web, encoding

For example, if I have a GBK encoded website, when users use Microsoft pinyin or Google pinyin to input some Chinese character, will these tools aware what is encoding the website used and input accordingly for example, Google pinyin will output GBK encoding characters when the website is GBK encoded or output UTF-8 characters if the website is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: The IMEs output *characters*, which are handled in whatever way the OS handles any text. When the form on the website is submitted to the server, at that point the browser will take care of encoding the text in the appropriate encoding, depending on what the form or website specified.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. let's say I have a form in the GBK encoding website, then i use some IMEs Chinese input tool to type some Chinese characters in that form and it display correctly doesn't it mean already encoded to GBK?  if the browser only take care the encoding when the form is submitting, then if i want to use JavaScript to do regex operation how can I match the Chinese characters correctly?

Comment: The website loads in the browser, the browser *decodes* text from GBK into *characters*. At this point GBK or any other encoding is irrelevant, text is just text now. You then input some *text*. Then you submit the form, and the browser *encodes* the text to a specific encoding.